# Есть способ в отладчике Eclipse приостановить выполнение при изменении выбранной переменной?

Tags: отладка, eclipse

Есть какой-нибудь способ в отладчике в Eclipse приостановить выполнение программы не по breakpoint, а при изменении значения выбранной переменной?
На тот случай, когда непонятно, где надо ставить breakpoint, чтобы найти причину изменений.

Comment: Нашёл. Breakpoint надо ставить на строке, где объявляется переменная. А потом right click на этом breakpoint, зайти в properties и там есть флажки "Access" и "Modification".

Answer (score 1):

[читаем](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint%3F) до просветления. Термин этой задачи такой: **conditional breakpoint**

Answer (score 0):

> а при изменении значения выбранной
> переменной?

она же меняется при каком-то условии, так вот там и ставь breakpoint

Comment: Всё, что я знаю, это то, что у меня изменяются 3 переменные. Измениться они могут из десятков разных мест. Я не знаю, где ставить breakpoint, чтобы отловить изменения.

Comment: поставь точки останова на все 3 переменные, найди места в коде, где вызываются методы, которые изменяют эти переменные..